# SWIFT: Animation changes speeds, which I don't want

Tags: ios, swift, animation, label

I'm trying to create a Star Wars style scrolling text for a viewController.

I have the following code:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

    UIView.animate(withDuration: 60.0, animations: {
        let width = self.scrollingTextLabel.frame.width
        let height = self.scrollingTextLabel.frame.height
        self.scrollingTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: (180 - height), width: width, height: height)
    }, completion:{ _ in
        self.buttonTextLabel.text = "Play"
    })

}
```

It works perfectly except for 1 thing, it speeds up, then slows down. This means, it's hard to read at the mid point. Is there a way to make the speed constant?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass in `.curveLinear` in the animation options to make the animation have a constant velocity:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 60.0, delay: 0.0, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
    let width = self.scrollingTextLabel.frame.width
    let height = self.scrollingTextLabel.frame.height
    self.scrollingTextLabel.frame = CGRect(x: 5, y: (180 - height), width: width, height: height)
}, completion:{ _ in
    self.buttonTextLabel.text = "Play"
})
```

Comment: This is the right answer. (Voted.) Some background: Animations use different timing curves. By default, animations use "ease-in, ease-out" timing, which means the animation starts at 0 speed, accelerates to full speed, uses a constant speed through the middle portion, and then coasts to a stop at the end. To change the animation's timing curve you need to use one of the forms of animate() that takes an options parameter, like `animate(withDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:)`, and pass in an options value of `.curveLinear`